# GCC adds some paddings to the end of the buffer, how to disable this

Tags: c

I am learning how to exploit a stack. Below codes:

```
/* bofvulcode.c */
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  /* declare a buffer with max 512 bytes in size*/
  char mybuff[512];

  /* verify the input */
  if(argc < 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: %s <string_input_expected>\n", argv[0]);
    exit (0);
  }

  /* else if there is an input, copy the string into the buffer */
  strcpy(mybuff, argv[1]);

  /* display the buffer's content */
  printf("Buffer's content: %s\n", mybuff);
  return 0;
}
```

I have disabled ASLR using:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

And I compiled the codes using:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -g -w bofvulcode.c -o bofvulcode
```

The buffer's size is 512, so more than 512 bytes are enough to cause a segmentation fault.
But I find that I have to use at least 520 bytes to crash the program.

```
jack@jack-VirtualBox:~/workspace$ ./bofvulcode `perl -e 'print "A"x519'`
Buffer's content:   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA


jack@jack-VirtualBox:~/workspace$ ./bofvulcode `perl -e 'print "A"x520'`
Buffer's content: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So I assumes that GCC has added some kind of paddings to the end of the buffer. I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't mean seg fault.

Comment: I take it this is for amusement only?

Answer (score 2):

traditionally stack grows from top to bottom. pushing at stack means decreasing the stack pointer.
so then your main function is entered. the return adress, and the parameters are passed to stack. the parameters are 8bytes, the next element is your 512byte array that. so that the stacks looks like this.

```
| 0 | 1 | 2.. 512 array-bytes | argv | argC | return adress |
```

so your first 512 bytes simply are written correct to array buffer. the next 8 bytes overwrite your function parameters and writes after that destroy the return address. when the main routines is exited this finally causes your program to crash, since the return try to jump to an invalid address.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that because you've asked for 512 bytes that accessing beyond 512 bytes will cause a segfault. Memory is allocated to a process by pages (e.g., 4K at a time) and cannot be allocated by lesser amounts.

Comment: Memory can't be allocated to a process in smaller amounts; but real memory allocation strategies don't do that. The stack is reserved once at program start, and is quite happy to allocate 1 byte for the user if that's what they need.

Comment: @BillyONeal he said "allocated _to a process_".  The OS allocates memory to processes, in page-sized chunks as advertised.  Ooga, still, this would be better off as a comment.

Comment: @jthill: Ah, you're right. Removed downvote.

Comment: but its still wrong or irrelevant for the problem. his array is on stack and the stack has a much greater size than just a half kB or 4kB and it is allocated on program loading

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Good point. I agree.